# Garrys Mod lua kick and gag Troubble

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I've got a Server and want to add tabs to the menu I've put in the command

```
local force = actions:AddOption( "Kick Player from the game" )
force:SetIcon( "icon16/delete.png" )
function force:DoClick()
  RunConsoleCommand("ulx kick","reason", ply:EntIndex())
end
```

But i Get This Error sign

```
RunConsoleCommand: Command has invalid characters! (ulx kick (' '))
        The first parameter of this function should contain only the command, the second parameter should contain arguments.
```

PLEASE Can anyone help me

Comment: Try using `RunConsoleCommand( "kick", ply:EntIndex() )`. According to the [list of commands](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170589737), ULX kick command doesn't accept reason argument.

Comment: `kick` is an argument to the `ulx` command. Separate them into different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is `ulx`
Your arguments are: `kick`, `reason` and `ply:EntIndex()`

So instead of

```
RunConsoleCommand("ulx kick","reason", ply:EntIndex())
```

the line should be:

```
RunConsoleCommand("ulx", "kick", ply:EntIndex(), "reason")
```

'cause the first argument of the function should only contain the command you want to call.

Source: your Error Message ("The first parameter of this function should contain only the command, [...]") and
http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Global/RunConsoleCommand